# Building HTML dynamically with knockout

Tags: c#, html, knockout.js

I have a single-page-application in MVC4 project in C#.

In my HTML I have a like-a-table lists - first  is the table titles, and second  is in a div with a "foreach" property (knockout) and presents all the items in my list.

Now, I need this "table" to be dynamic - I'll get a list of columns and "instructions" (column title, column class name, column value name, css conditions, etc.) and the HTML will be built dynamically.
Is it possible with knockout?

This is my code now. There are only 5 columns. I need it to be dynamic so I can easily add (and remove) columns by changing the instruction list, whithout touching the HTML.

```
    <ul class="assetsTitles">
        <li class="ItemKey" data-bind="click: sortBy.bind($data, 'Key'), css: { selected: Filter().OrderBy() == 'Key', desc: Filter().Descending() }"><span>Key</span></li>
        <li class="ItemName" data-bind="click: sortBy.bind($data, 'Name'), css: { selected: Filter().OrderBy() == 'Name', desc: Filter().Descending() }"><span>Item Name</span></li>
        <li class="ItemProp1" data-bind="click: sortBy.bind($data, 'ItemProp1'), css: { selected: Filter().OrderBy() == 'ItemProp1', desc: Filter().Descending() }">ItemProp1</li>
        <li class="ItemProp2" data-bind="click: sortBy.bind($data, 'ItemProp2'), css: { selected: Filter().OrderBy() == 'ItemProp2', desc: Filter().Descending() }">ItemProp2</li>
        <li class="ItemProp3" data-bind="click: sortBy.bind($data, 'ItemProp3'), css: { selected: Filter().OrderBy() == 'ItemProp3', desc: Filter().Descending() }">ItemProp3</li>
    </ul>

<div data-bind="foreach: items, visible: items().length > 0">
    <div class="itemRow" data-bind=" attr: { id: RowId() }">
        <ul class="itemRowDetails " data-bind="visible: ShowDetails, selected: IsSelected, click: $parent.showItemDetails.bind($data, $data, $parent.type), css: { selected: IsSelected() }">
            <li class="ItemKey" data-bind=" title: Key"><span data-bind="text: Key" /></li>
            <li class="ItemName" data-bind=" title: Name"><span data-bind="text: Name" /></li>
            <li class="ItemProp1" data-bind=" title: ItemProp1"><span data-bind="text: ItemProp1" /></li>
            <li class="ItemProp2" data-bind=" title: ItemProp2"><span data-bind="text: ItemProp2" /></li>
            <li class="ItemProp3" data-bind=" title: ItemProp3Display"><span data-bind="text: ItemProp3Display, css: { alertDetail: ItemProp3Alert, alertDetail2: ItemProp3Alert2 }" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes. It is possible. What's wrong with the current code?

Comment: It's not dynamic. It's hard-coded. I need to get a list of column and properties.

Comment: If I want to add a column - I need to change the HTML. I don't want to do that, I want it to be dynamic, following the instruction set that I want to send to the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can  use ko.renderTemplate 
and  doing some thing like :

```
  <!-- ko foreach:$root.visibleColumns() -->\
     <li  data-bind=\"attr:{'data-columnname' : columnName}\" role=\"column\" ><span  data-bind=\"attr:{'class': columnHeaderCss, 'data-columnname' : columnName,'data-headertext': headerText}, text: headerText\"></span> </li>\
  <!-- /ko -->\
```

and pass the columns list  to viewModel :

```
 ko.dataGrid = {
    viewModel: function (configuration) {
         var me = this;
          $.extend(me, {
            columns: configuration.columns,
             visibleColumns: function () {
                   var res = [];
                    $.each(me.columns, function (i, c) {
                        if (c.visible)
                            res.push(c);
                    });

                return res;
            },
          });
      }
```

Comment: Great, but not 100%. I have two lists. One with the instructions (me.columns) and one with the items. I need one line to take values from both lists, for example - class from "instructions" and text value from the items (according the right column). How can I do that?

Comment: that because im using "addTemplate(templateName, templateMarkup) " function ,     templateEngine.addTemplate("dataGrid", "\ <!-- ko foreach:$root.visibleColumns() -->\
     <li  data-bind=\"attr:{'data-columnname' : columnName}\" role=\"column\" ><span  data-bind=\"attr:{'class': columnHeaderCss, 'data-columnname' : columnName,'data-headertext': headerText}, text: headerText\"></span> </li>\
  <!-- /ko -->\")

Comment: you can send  as much array as you want via "configuration" as you can see in my sample i use : "text: headerText" , header text could be bind like columns  you can extend your viewModel

Comment: It's great for the titles but I'm having trouble with the items themselfs - show the item's column value - item.'columnName' (item.Key, item.Prop1, etc.): <div data-bind="foreach: items, visible: items().length > 0"> <div data-bind="foreach: $parent.columns"> <div data-bind="attr:{'class': columnName}"><span data-bind="text: ???item.columnName???" /></div> </div> </div>

Comment: OK I found the way to do it - item[columnName]()

Answer (score 0):

You could try building the html in script using traditional techniques then attach it to an element. Then to add this to the binding the name of that element needs to be included as a 2nd parameter:

ko.applyBindings(viewModel, dynamicElement)

Alternatively ko has html ("html:") and text binding ("text:") options.

In constructing the html in code you may need to use the "containerless control flow syntax" i.e. wrap within the comment notation e.g. `<!-- ko foreach: myItems --> .... <!-- /ko -->` Where myItems is an array.

Usual caveats apply regarding possible injection attacks!

Its been some time since I played with ko..